# Can we store bigint data type in sqlite using room greater than 64 bits

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I need to use number value greater than 64 bits do sqlite database will store it.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Sqlite?

Comment: I am using sqlite in android

Comment: How is that represented in android? Is it "integer" (just bigger) or floating point?

Comment: For SQLite the integer data type has maximum capacity of 64 bits.

Comment: @forpas so, only last thing is to use String instead of bigint

Comment: You can store anything to any data type in SQLite. So you can store an integer larger than 64 bit.s to an integer column but you will lose precision because it will be converted to real. If this is not what you want then use TEXT as data type.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite only supports five datatypes: `TEXT`, `INTEGER`, `REAL`, `BLOB`, and `NULL`. However, both `Integer` and `Real` can only store 8-byte values(64-bits). If your big-int variable is greater than 8 digits/bytes you have to use a workaround. First, convert the number to a string before saving it to SQLite and then parse it to an integer/bigInt/double once you retrieve it. If the number is too big (longer than 256 bytes), you can opt to store it as a string using the `BLOB` data type.